# Plugin BLE (v1.3.0) delay after characteristic.ReadAsync()

Tags: xamarin.forms

I’m developing an app and I want to read some characteristics one after one.

My issue is that after a read is done I must do a delay otherwise I get an error.

Why does it need a delay ? is there a way to write correctly read tasks one after other ?

I'm using Xamarin.forms and Ble v1.3.0 plugin.
I've tried "await Task.Delay(200)" between two consecutive ReadAsync() functions and it works fine but if I remove the delay, the second ReadAsync gets exception.

```
private async Task ReadChr(ICharacteristic LocalCharacteristic)
{
  byte[] localData = { };
  if (LocalCharacteristic.CanRead)
  {
    try
    {
      return localData = await LocalCharacteristic.ReadAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      return null;
    }
  }
}

if (firstCharacteristic.CanRead)
{
  var ccc = await ReadChr(firstCharacteristic);
}
await Task.Delay(200);
if (secondCharacteristic.CanRead)
{
  var ddd = await ReadChr(secondCharacteristic);
}
```

I'm searching something like polling the read process status of the characteristic. Delay after ReadAsync does not seem a good practice coding.
Any idea ?

Comment: Do you want to read multiple Characteristic values at the same time?Maybe your Bluetooth device allows only one channel for communication at the same time.

Comment: There is no problem to read all the characteristic of my service. I'm searching when ReadAsync is completed before We can launch another call to the function.